# Looking for a pure Javascript Functional programming solution

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I've been challenging myself with solving this in pure functional programming style, in `Javascript`.
The problem is this:

*Input:*

```
var src = [{n:3, x:2}, {n:6, x:1}, {n:2, x:0}, {n:10, x:5}, {n:5, x:2}, {n:1, x:44}];
```

*Problem definition:*

Group the items in the `src` array using a either a predicate or a hash function and sum the `item.x` values for each group.
For example, in the output I pasted the grouping is the remainder division of `item.n` with 2

*Output:*

```
var trgt = [
  {sum:48, items: [{n:3, x:2}, {n:5, x:2}, {n:1, x:44}]},
  {sum:6, items: [{n:6, x:1}, {n:2, x:0}, {n:10, x:5}]}
]
```

The goal here is to find as pure a functional programming solution as possible.

Here is [my solution](http://jsbin.com/zecuqe/1/edit?js,output)

```
function moduloTwo(val) {
  return (val.n % 2);
}
function makeObjectAndAdd(hashFn) {
  return function (result, curr) {
    if (result[hashFn(curr)] === undefined) {
      result[hashFn(curr)] = {sum: 0, items: []};
    }
    var newObj = result[hashFn(curr)];
    newObj.items.push(curr);
    newObj.sum += curr.x;

    return result;
  };
}

var result = src.reduce(makeObjectAndAdd(moduloTwo), {});
```

I feel that it could be made to be more "`functional`".

Thanks!

Comment: the link points to the output, not your solution. output is not "functional". Code is.

Comment: You should paste the relevant code into the question directly, not only a link to it. Maybe the linked site is not reachable (anymore) and then the question couldn't be answered or makes no sense at all :)

Comment: Changed link to point to code.

Comment: I don't see the point of *isDividedByTwo* as a separate function. It should be called *isEven* and could be simply `return !(val%2)` since the name infers that it will return a boolean.

Comment: @RobG Like I said, you can either return a predicate or a hash function. For example, what if you would want to group by the result of `%3`? It wouldn't work with `true`/`false`. At-least not for this solution. I agree that the function name is misleading though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your code more functionally using Ramda.js as follows:

1. Given an input:

   ```
   var input = [
       { n:  3, x:  2 },
       { n:  6, x:  1 },
       { n:  2, x:  0 },
       { n: 10, x:  5 },
       { n:  5, x:  2 },
       { n:  1, x: 44 }
   ];
   ```
2. We first separate them into odd and even groups based on the property `n`:

   ```
   var oddN = R.compose(odd, R.prop("n"));

   var groups = R.groupBy(oddN, input);

   function odd(n) {
       return n % 2 === 1;
   }
   ```
3. Then we get the values of all the groups, pluck the `x` property of each item and summate:

   ```
   var output = R.map(count, R.values(groups));

   function count(items) {
       return {
           sum:   R.sum(R.pluck("x", items)),
           items: items
       };
   }
   ```

See the online demo for yourself: http://bit.ly/1IawqzD

Comment: I like Ramda a lot. I talk about it when explaining Functional Programming to Javascript devs

Comment: I don't like Ramda, but it's the least bad functional library we've got.

Comment: Within the confides of JavaScript I think it does a good job.